# c# : comparing two lists and recording change in value

Tags: c#, list, compare

most answers that I have seen here are mostly covering the issue of boolean true/false upon list comparison. What I am interested in is comparing two lists and seeing the change in the value between the two lists.

In other words, I have list and list; they both have two entries-- name and a grade: in list a, the first entry is "Tom", and his grade is "100", in list b, the first entry is also "Tom", but his grade is now "89".

My pathetic attempt to do this:

```
private static void DataFromResults(List<data> aList, List<data> bList)
{
    using (var reader = newStreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"c:\temp\data.csv")))
    {       
        while(!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var line = reader.ReadLine();
            var values = line.Split(',');
            string name = new name(values[0]).ToString();

            string grade = new grade(values[1]).ToString();
            foreach (var data in aList)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < aList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (aList[i] != bList[i]) {//???}...
```

Comment: So do you first need to join by name, or are you okay to assume the lists are in the same order? What do you want the result to be? There isn't really enough information for us to help you at the moment...

Comment: I assume that lists are in the same order, yes

Comment: the result has to be Console.Writeline output saying that Tom's result went down by 11%

Comment: Right, so the point about the name being "Tom" is irrelevant, you're just comparing the grade parts? We still don't know what you want the result to be...

Comment: yes, the name part is irrelevant - we are only comparing grades, and we see 11 percent decrease from value 100% to 89%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want something like:

```
var differences = aList.Zip(bList,
     (a, b) => new { a.Name, Difference = a.Grade - b.Grade });

foreach (var result in differences)
{
    if (result.Difference != 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Change for {0}: {1}", result.Name, result.Difference);
    }
}
```

(If you want it proportional rather than absolute, you probably want to keep the initial value as well...)

The [`Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd267698(v=vs.100).aspx) method basically matches up elements in two sequences (in order) and projects each pair into another value, according to the projection you provide.

Comment: Thank you Jon for your help!

Comment: @mrsphd - Please mark Jon's response as the answer.  He is in dire need of points.